# How does this code print same PrimeFactors?

Tags: java

This code print the prime factors of a number.
I wanted to know how does it print the same Prime Factor twice 
eg: 45 => 3.3.5

```
// get the number

  for(int i = 2; i< number; i++) {
     while(number%i == 0) {
        System.out.println(i+" ");
        number = number/i;
     }
  }
  if(number >2) {
     System.out.println(number);
  }
```

Comment: The inner loop will repeat the as many times as `i` is a factor.

Comment: Just run through the code on a sheet of paper.  `i=2` is a no-op, because `45` is not divisible by `2`.  For `i=3`, the `while` loop will execute _twice_, printing `3` twice.  Then, it will print `5` later for `i=5`.

Comment: try debugging it

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen why don't you post it as an answer? Is it your personal choice or SO encourages to put answers in comment for minor/silly question? As this is very common scenario, I'm just curious! Thanks.

Comment: thanks all I completely get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when i = 3, while loop iterates two times.
In first iteration it will print 3 and update value of number = 15
As number is updated it will again iterate.
In second iteration it will again print 3 and update value of number = 5
now, (5%3 == 0) is not possible so it will not iterate third time.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest/best way to understand what the code is doing is to run through it.  You could try using a debugger on your end, but we can also try to summarize here:

```
i = 2
nothing happens, because 45 is not divisible by 2

i = 3
the while loop iterates twice, printing 3 twice, and also setting
number = 45 -> 15 -> 5

i = 4
nothing happens, because 45 is not divisible by 4

i = 5
the while loop iterates once, printing 5 once, and setting number = 5 / 5 = 1
```

At this point, the outer `for` loop fails, because `i = 5` and `number = 1`.